# selecting files.csv in R

Tags: regex, r

I need to select all the files inside a folder in format .csv that contains only non numerical characters.

I use the following code, but it selects only 9 files of 13 with the chosen pattern. Is it right?

I select files like Berlin.csv

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="[:alpha:].csv", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = FALSE)
length(ldf)
ldf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like:

```
list.files(pattern = "^[[:alpha:]]+\\.csv")
```

That pattern will match any CSV that starts with and contains only alphabetical characters. But, if you want to allow filenames with other non-alphabetic characters (e.g., spaces, punctuation), use something like this:

```
list.files(pattern = "^[^[:digit:]]+\\.csv")
```

That will just exclude any filenames that have a number in them. (Note the two different meanings of `^` when used inside and outside of a character class.)

Comment: Thomas thanks, one questions, what does it make ^ and +?

Comment: @EnricAgudPique `^` at the beginning of the regex in this context means "beginning of filename"; inside the character class (`[^]`) it means negation (so the second example means "not matching digits". The `+` means "one or more" of the preceding characters (so, in the first example, the regex matches one or more alphabetical characters from the beginning of the filename until the file extension).